# How to add static home page in dspace for root domain(URL)?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, dspace

I am working with dspace 6 version and trying to implement the static home page for dspace, when user visits my repo, he /she will be landing to this static homepage and this homepage has all the links to navigate for the discovery and browse by items links.

Does any body has tried this.

I find some info about creating a static about page, and did the same thing to match the "/" url as like the static about page, but didn't work.

Here is the code, that how I call my static template in XMLUI

```
 <xsl:when test="starts-with($request-uri, 'xmlui')">
                    <xsl:call-template name="homePage"/>
                    <!-- inject homepage for / url -->
                    <div class="hero-unit">
                        <h1>This is home page
                            We will add the banner here
                        </h1>
                    </div>

 </xsl:when>
```

The content of home page is pure html and css as shown below

```
 <xsl:template name="homePage">

    <!-- Banner -->
    <h1>Welcome to our digital repo </h1>
    <!-- other code here -->
 </xsl:template>
```